# Trouble getting result for my redirect logic to profile page in node.js, express, mongodb web app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using node.js, express, and monogodb. I was trying to create a web app where when a user logged in it redirects to his profile page. I have created login logic and route as:

```
//Show login Form

app.get("/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("login");
});

//handling login logic

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
    {
        successRedirect: "/users/show",
        failureRedirect: "/login"

    }), function(req, res){
});
```

and route for the profile as:

```
//USER PROFILE
app.get("users/:id", function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, founddUser){
        if(err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong");
            res.redirect("/")
        }
        res.render("users/show", {user: foundUser});
    });

});
```

Folder and file structure as. But when I run it shows Cannot GET /users/show

view-users-show.ejs

```
//show profile page route
app.get("/users/show", function(req, res){
    res.render("users/show");
});
```

show.ejs as below

```
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2><%= user.firstName + " " + user.lastName %></h2>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="<%= user.avatar %>">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <p>
        Welcome to your profile page
      </p>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Please, any help. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you routing the /users/show path to a view? The request will fail if this is not done. Also, I think you forgot to paste the code for view-users-show.ejs

Comment: thanks for your response. I was able to redirect to the profile page. But the new problem is  it throws an error in the page as:
the user is not defined

Comment: I added  /users/show path to a view and my show.ejs in my original question.

Comment: This is probably a new question at this point but it sounds like you're not adding a User document to the database. If this isn't the case I'd need more code to properly answer your question.